# How to exclude folder creation from triggering an AWS EventBridge rule?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-event-bridge

I'd like to have an EventBridge rule that is triggered only when a file is uploaded into an S3 bucket, but I can't figure out how to specify the Event pattern that doesn't trigger the rule with the creation of a new folder inside the bucket. Every pattern I tried triggers the rule when a folder is created inside the bucket. This is the pattern I'm using:

```
{
  "detail-type": ["AWS API Call via CloudTrail"],
  "source": ["aws.s3"],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": ["s3.amazonaws.com"],
    "requestParameters": {
      "bucketName": ["my-bucket"],
      "key": [{
        "prefix": "some-prefix"
      }]
    },
    "eventName": ["PutObject", "CompleteMultipartUpload", "CopyObject", "POST Object"]
  }
}
```

With this pattern, the rule is triggered both when a file is uploaded and a folder is created inside the bucket. Is there a way to solve this problem only by using the EventBridge rule?

Comment: 'Folders' are objects too. Typically you would not have these folder objects, however. What is creating the folder object? If you need to, filter by size and ignore 0-sized objects whose key ends in `/`.

Comment: The folder objects have to be created, that's how the bucket structure is organized. Do you have an example for filtering objects by size and for keys that end with some symbol?

Comment: I've looked at this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-event-patterns-content-based-filtering.html , but I don't understand the JSON attributes they used in the examples.

Comment: You don't need folder objects in order to be able to store objects at a specific hierarchy e.g. `cats/` does not need to exist for you to be able to store `cats/persian.png`. However, if you cannot avoid it then the event parameter passed into your invoked Lambda will tell you both the object key and the object size. You can use those. You can also [filter events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-event-patterns-content-based-filtering.html) in EventBridge.

Comment: Yes, I guess that's the solution then. And regarding the filter events link you shared, I've already seen it, but I don't understand the attributes they used for the filtering in their examples, where did they find them would be my question.

Comment: Looks like there is no suffix filter option, which is less than ideal. That would seem to be a common requirement to me.

Comment: I agree, maybe Anything-but matching can be used in this case.

Comment: Yes, that might work. Anything but ["cats/", "dogs/"], for example.